# Password Protecting a PDF Generated in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf, password-protection, alivepdf

I'm using the [alivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/) library to generate PDFs in my AIR application with AS3. Is there a way to password protect or otherwise encrypt the PDFs I generate? Even if it's a different AS3 library, as long as I don't have to make the client install and run a second program, it would be fine.

Thanks!

Comment: The hurlant as3crypto library is what you are looking for.

Comment: as3crypto has nothing to do with password protecting PDFs. That feature has been added and i believe the devs are supposed to add it to the next release. The only way i believe for you is to generate your PDF in php...